# Insertar en MySQL si no existe un campo

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo puedo insertar una en MySQL sólo si no existe un campo?

Por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellidos, edad) VALUES ('Nombre', 'Apellidos', 25) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nombre FROM persona WHERE nombre = 'Daniel')
```

Comment: El insert no es condicional, el update lo es, debes verificar antes de hacer el insert si existe.

Comment: Gracais por contestar! ¿Y cómo lo verifico?

Comment: Con un trigger? con una variable? no sabemos que estas haciendo ni como, ni como es tu sistema como para darte una respuesta definitiva

Comment: Que condicion quisieras colocar para insertart?

Answer (score 1):

Si en la tabla `persona` existe al menos 1 registro distinto del valor que se está buscando, entonces utilizando la sintaxis [`INSERT... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) se puede lograr:

#### Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellidos, edad) 
SELECT 'Nombre', 'Apellidos', 25
FROM personas
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nombre FROM persona WHERE nombre = 'Daniel')
LIMIT 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b24c4c/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Si actualmente hay N personas en la tabla y ninguna se llama `Daniel`, este código va a intentar insertar N nuevos registros con los mismos datos, no **uno** nuevo, que parece ser la intención del AP, sino potencialmente muchos.

Comment: A lo que voy es a que, si existen 25 registros, inserta 25 registros nuevos. Eso no parece ser la intencion del AP.

Comment: Marcos, no pillé el _limit 1_ de tu consulta, hasta ahora que probé el _Demo_. Eso previene lo que he venido diciendo, una disculpa, que he sido yo el que te ha robado el tiempo innecesariamente.

Answer (score 0):

lo que deberias hacer en este caso un SP. (stored procedure)

en donde verifique

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIfNoExist
AS
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT nombre FROM persona WHERE nombre = 'Daniel' )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellidos, edad) VALUES ('Nombre', 'Apellidos', 25) 
END
```

Solo declara los parametros a insertar y  los parametros las propiedades de tu objeto persona. cuando lo vayas implementar, checate la estructura de un SP
Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Depende ¿de que? es lo que quieres verificar si existe.
A juzgar por tu consulta sql, entiendo que quieres que se inserte el nuevo registro, solo si el nombre no existe en la base de datos.
El problema de la consulta que colocas, tiene problemas de sintaxis y ademas no considera el campo "apellido" en ningun momento.
Pero te planteo 1 de 2 posibles soluciones:
puedes crear un indice "unique" agregando los campos "nombre y apellido"
de esa forma Mysql no permite que se inserten registros cuando intentes registrar un nombre y apellido similar, lanzando un error de entrada duplicada.
puedes crear la tabla asi:

```
CREATE TABLE `persona` (
`nombres` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`apellidos` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`edad` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `nombres_sin_repetir` (`nombres`, `apellidos`))COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';
```

El servidor lanzará un error si intentas registrar algo que ya existe, entonces modificas la consulta de insercion para evitar esto, indicando de antemano que si le llega un valor repetido, actualice el valor por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO persona (nombres, apellidos, edad) VALUES ('valor','valor',15) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nombres = nombres, apellidos = apellidos;
```

O hacer un INSERT IGNORE

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO persona (nombres, apellidos, edad) VALUES ('valor','valor',15);
```

Espero te sirva, y si no es lo que buscas nos comentas para brindarte una solucion